# Not able to upload .XAP file while submitting app dev center

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have  developed a windowsphone7 app, i used visual studio 2010 and WP7 SDK to develop that app, and i have a registered developer account.

Now the app is ready to upload in market place,i have the XAP file.

I goes through the app submitting process, at package upload step, it allows only the ".appxupload" file, but not the ".xap" file.

Can anybody guide me to upload my app xap file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: When you click the "Browse" button, a dialog box is open.  And there you can select your xap file.  I tried just now and it allows me to select ".xap" file.

Comment: What browser are you using? I know it sounds crazy but I can NEVER do submissions if I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows 8 Store http://dev.windows.com  requires .appxupload

Windows Phone Store http://dev.windowsphone.com requires .xap

If you have .xap and its asking for .appxupload, you are in the wrong store.

Comment: This needs more upvotes. I spent a long time not realizing the two stores were different. I saw a lot of forum threads that always pointed to Windows Store documentation which was like "Look at the Store menu" which doesn't exist! (for windows phone dev)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual XAP upload component still uses Silverlight (I always see the Silverlight loading animation appear when I upload). Try ensuring you have Silverlight installed and are using a browser that supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using Internet Explorer with silverlight installed otherwise it just hangs and crashes. DONT use Chrome. It is a death sentence for app submission.